# Nested Array json from API for Data Table Angular

Tags: angular, multidimensional-array, nested

I have a problem in angular, I have one API that has return nested array. I want to grab that data for build a data table in angular. But I've try to use ngFor nested loop and others way, but until now I can't get the result

API that I have is this

```js
{
    "data": [
        {
            "attendances": [
                {
                    "employee": "08850046-WIDI TRI YUWONO",
                    "attendance_date": "2020-07-01",
                    "attendance_day": "WEDNESDAY",
                    "checkin_time": "-",
                    "checkin_location": "-",
                    "checkout_time": "-",
                    "checkout_location": "-",
                    "checkin_status": 0
                },
                {
                    "employee": "08850046-WIDI TRI YUWONO",
                    "attendance_date": "2020-07-02",
                    "attendance_day": "THURSDAY",
                    "checkin_time": "-",
                    "checkin_location": "-",
                    "checkout_time": "-",
                    "checkout_location": "-",
                    "checkin_status": 0
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "attendances": [
                {
                    "employee": "93710016-MAYA SETYAWATI",
                    "attendance_date": "2020-07-01",
                    "attendance_day": "WEDNESDAY",
                    "checkin_time": "-",
                    "checkin_location": "-",
                    "checkout_time": "-",
                    "checkout_location": "-",
                    "checkin_status": 0
                },
                {
                    "employee": "93710016-MAYA SETYAWATI",
                    "attendance_date": "2020-07-02",
                    "attendance_day": "THURSDAY",
                    "checkin_time": "-",
                    "checkin_location": "-",
                    "checkout_time": "-",
                    "checkout_location": "-",
                    "checkin_status": 0
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <app-card cardTitle="{{ 'CHART_COMPONENT.attendance_history' | translate }}" cardClass="card-datatable" headerClass="text-center text-md-left" [hidHeader]="false" [options]="true" [loading]="loadtableEmployeeStaffReport">
      <div class="table-responsive pb-1">
        <table datatable [dtOptions]="dtOptions" class="table table-bordered table-hover" [dtTrigger]="dtTrigger">
          <thead class="thead-light">
            <tr>
              <th scope="col" style="padding-left: 10px">No.</th>
              <th scope="col" style="text-align:center">Employee</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>


          <tbody *ngIf="tableData?.length != 0;">
            <tr *ngFor="let data of tableData; let i = index;">
              <tr *ngFor="let col of data.attendances; let j = index;"></tr>
                <th scope="row" style="padding-left: 10px">{{ j+1 }}</th>
                <th scope="row" style="padding-left: 10px">{{ j+1 }}</th>
              </tr>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
          <tbody *ngIf="tableData?.length == 0 && !loadtableEmployeeStaffReport">
            <tr>
              <td colspan="7" class="no-data-available text-center">Data tidak ditemukan!</td>
              <td class="hidden"></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
          <tbody *ngIf="tableData?.length == 0 && loadtableEmployeeStaffReport">
            <tr>
              <td colspan="7" class="no-data-available text-center">Loading Data....</td>
              <td class="hidden"></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </app-card>
  </div>
```

```js
this.chartService.getEmployeeReportStaff().subscribe(response => {
      setTimeout(() => { 
        this.tableData = response.data;
        this.dtTrigger.next(); 
        this.loadtableEmployeeStaffReport = false;
      }, 3000);
    }
```

Please kindly give me some inspirations for build that datatable. I use component.ts and .html for view.

Comment: can you share the html code?

Comment: I've insert HTML and .TS script that I used. Thank you